# Beginner problem: Debugging power supply

Tags: power-supply, dc, oscilloscope, wiring, debugging

I am debugging my power supply using an oscilloscope. I have uploaded pictures of my setup, including oscilloscope reading, wiring (just power and ground with jumpers), and the power supply specs. The power supply is supposed to output 5V 10A DC, but the oscilloscope at 1X is reading ~480mV. Is this power supply bad, is there something wrong with my setup, am I reading the oscilloscope incorrectly, or is it something else?

[image: osc reading]

[image: wiring]

[image: power supply specs]

Comment: Are you using a X10 scope probe?  If so, your 488 mV would really be 4.88 V.  Use a multimeter to verify the voltage.

Comment: It's from this oscilloscope, and I think the scope probe is X10: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07XBL4BTL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: If you tell the scope you are using a 10X probe, it will display the actual measured voltage. Usually in the input setup menu but that scope has a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree about the probe.

Also, switching power supplies, especially low-cost ones like yours, usually have a minimum load requirement.  10% is a common requirement "to stabilize the magnetics" (ooooold app note phrase).  Without this, the supply is not guaranteed to maintain regulation.